# Android activity not getting broadcast from local service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

From the examples this looked straightforward. Maybe you can show me what I did wrong. I can't get an activity to receive a broadcast sent from a local service.

I have Activity1 that start Service1:

```
startService(new Intent(Activity1.this, Service1.class));
```

Activity1 then starts Activity2:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
```

Service1, a local service, listens for downloads:

```
protected final BroadcastReceiver service2DownloadBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        ...
        broadcastDownloadFinished(Uri.fromFile(downloadedFile));
```

The broadcast receiver of Service1 then broadcasts its own message:

```
protected Intent broadcastDownloadFinished(final Uri uri)
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED).setData(checkNotNull(uri));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Activity2, which is in the foreground at the time, listens for the ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED intent using its own broadcast receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver activity2DownloadBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i(Activity2.class.getSimpleName(), "Received download event: " + intent.getAction() + " " + intent.getData());
```

Activity2 of course registers the receiver:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    final IntentFilter downloadIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    downloadIntentFilter.addAction(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(activity2DownloadBroadcastReceiver, downloadIntentFilter);
```

In case it matters, `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED` is something like `"com.example.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_FINISHED"`.

Service1 receives the download manager event in its receiver and apparently broadcasts its own custom event, but Activity2 never seems to receive it. What did I do wrong? Is it a problem to broadcast an intent in the middle of processing another one? (I wouldn't think so---this is asynchronous, right?)

*Update:* Just to make sure there is no problem sending a broadcast in the middle of receiving a broadcast, I changed my broadcast code to actually perform the broadcast three seconds later on the main thread:

```
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "...ready to broadcast");     
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED).setData(checkNotNull(uri));
    mainThreadHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "...broadcasting");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "...broadcasted");                
        }
    }, 3000);
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "...scheduled to broadcast");
```

As expected, the log says:

```
...ready to broadcast
...scheduled to broadcast
...broadcasting
...broadcasted
```

Yet nothing is received in the activity. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka! I found it! The problem is that I supplied a data URI in my broadcast intent. The Android intent matching rules get a little complicated. If you supply a data URI, then your intent filter must specify a matching MIME type.

Unfortunately, although the Android documentation says that the data type can be inferred from the data URI, apparently Android doesn't know that a `file://.../example.jpg` is an image. So this doesn't work:

```
intentFilter.addDataType("image/*");
```

However, instead of specifying a type, I can specify a scheme that I accept:

```
intentFilter.addDataScheme("file");
```

That works! It's a little rough---and a little artificial to restrict my broadcasts to `file:` URIs, but as that's all I'm using for the moment, it works.

Note that apparently I could manually specify the MIME type in the intent when I broadcast it, but that's too much trouble for now, as I'm downloading images from Picasa so I already know that they are images (and don't care the specific MIME type). And if it gets too much trouble, I could ditch the whole `setData()` thing altogether and set an extra---but of course I want to do things the Right Way.

Comment: You beat me to it. I hadn't spotted this self-answer and have just been looking at your code. I was going to suggest leaving the `setData(...)` out of the code just to see what happened - obviously (from your answer) it would have worked. Sorry I couldn't get on to it earlier - I had a late shift at work today. Glad you've got the solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this, MisterSquonk. This was driving me batty. I hope this winds up helping someone. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

have you included your receiver in your activity's manifest?

```
<receiver
  android:name=".YourReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action
      android:name="intent_name"></action>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: No. It is my understanding that this is not needed for a manually-registered receiver. Furthermore, the receiver is an inner class and cannot be registered in the manner you describe.

Comment: sure it can. set android:name=".ParentClass$ReceiverName"

Comment: Maybe I'm off-base here, but 1) I'm using an anonymous inner class, so you'd have to guess at the generated `...$Name`, 2) the whole point of the `<receiver>` element is to have Android automatically instantiate the receiver on an as-needed basis, and Android can't automatically instantiate my non-static, anonymous inner class, 3) my receiver class is already instantiated and registered, so the `<receiver>` element is not needed. Trying to get back on-topic: is `<receiver>` required for manually-registered receivers or not? I believe they are not.

Comment: Just to follow up: when manually registering a broadcast receiver, a static definition in the manifest is *not* needed; see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html .